# MVC - Creating a new controller vs creating a new method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-responsibility-principle

I have the following controller class:

```
SchoolController extends Controller:

// Mainly for AJAX requests
+ searchSchoolDataAction()
+ searchGradeDataAction()
+ searchPeriodDataAction()

// Entry point for a school website
+ schoolAction(shortName)

// Pre-enrolment process users from a certain school can perform
+ startPreEnrolmentAction(shortName)
+ preEnrolmentStudentAction(school)
+ preEnrolmentTutorAction(school)
```

And so on.

Now. It is a well known principle that we should keep controllers thin, and model thick. Additionally, controllers should also follow the Single Responsibility Principle. And my controllers have been gaining a lot of weight. So, here's the question: regarding best practices on MVC and OOP, when should I create a new controller, and when should I add a new method to a controller? Moreover, what's a good example of a controller method, or is this something left up to the programmer? (If the latter, it sounds a bit counterintuitive given it's a principle to be followed, but I'm not sure.) Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller should only deals with user request and Add a new Method only when you need to display web page. For example, you need to create CRUD for single Table suppose countries.

Your Controller Would be Countries. 
And Controller Actions represent Web pages Like, fetchAllAction, AddAction, UpdateAction, DeleteAction.

If your Project is for long time run, Then You Should build your Models on Enterprise Architecture. Enterprise Architecture Consist on four layers.
i) Data Model.
ii) Domain Logic Models.
iii) Mappers.
iv) Services.
Note: Service Layer is the only gateway and Public Face to your Controller.

Comment: "Note: Service Layer is the only gateway and Public Face to your Controller." Which means the Controller should not see the model, but rather the services which in turn contact the model. Is this correct? If so, this explains extremely well what the controller methods should do (even when it wasn't what I was asking about, but you just solved another doubt I had).

Now, as for the rest of the answer... 1 web page = 1 method. And when do I add a new controller? 1 controller = 1 class, or 1 controller = some classes?

Comment: In services layer all data model objects, mappers object and business logic are instantiated, In Simple words Service layer can communicate with other layer but controller only access service layer.

Comment: your controller should be domain specific. for example, If your are creating blog, all the methods relating blog are written in blog controller.  Note: controller should be Domain specific, it helps maintainability of the application. You Should Study "Domain Driven application"
1 controller = 1 class, or 1 controller = some classes. both are right, this is depend on your application requirement.

Comment: I am going to mark this as my accepted answer, as you pointed me out to DDD and gave me extra advice on best practices. Plus I got to solve my main question taking DDD into consideration. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, SRP is important when designing both controller methods and new controller.

Consider your basic controller method should only contain logic like filling view models from DB/service query and rendering viewmodel to your view.

SRP on creating controllers should be on a broader sense. From my experience it is a combination of maintenance, extensibility and user experience consideration.

Consider the case of the "Accounting" section in a CRM system. You may want to use one controller to represent all aspects of accounting department, but you can also break it into "Invoice", "Tax", "Payroll", etc. Using multiple controllers can improve user experience as they will know from the URI what you page is actually doing. And multiple controllers allow you to slim down your massive controllers into multiple specific controllers.

Comment: If I understand correctly, one controller should answer to one base URI. `InvoiceController` should only answer to `/invoice` and `TaxController` should only answer to `/tax`. This actually simplifies the process of thinking when a new controller class is needed. Now, let's say I have a project management system, and a `Project` class has many `Issue`s. So, if I want to edit the `Issue`s, I must access the `Project` first. Do I add one controller for `Project` and one for `Issue`, or do I mix both in one controller class? (Consider the URI is `/project/<id>/issues`)

Comment: I would say, at the end of the day, it depends on how you design your site structure in some case. First of all you can route /invoice and /tax to one controller if you want to use just one controller. Say for your example project management system, I might add another controller just for Issue. After all an Issue is a pretty big subject in a typical Project management system. Also user might as well add an issue and assign it to desired project.

Comment: And here goes the point of my question. When do I consider adding a new controller? For instance, does the following logic work? "If I must add CRUD over a certain class, it belongs to a new Controller". Or maybe I'm thinking this is way too complex? In my OP I could say each of the search methods belong to a separate class, except `searchSchoolDataAction` and `schoolAction`. The PreEnrolment methods could belong to a new class aswell, like, `EnrolmentController`. Am I right thinking on that logic, despite the routes each method might take?